# Pointer declaration in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, dll

This may be a stupid beginners question but I do not get it. I have a DLL which declares a function

```
int get_state(const unsigned char n,unsigned int *state)
```

What is the related C# import statement? Is

```
public static extern int get_card(byte n,ref uint state);
[DllImport(@"my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

correct?

And when using this function, *how* do I have to call `get_card()` in order to get the data out of the parameter returned in `state`?

Thanks!

Comment: Attribute `[DllImport(@"my.dll"...]` must be *before* (or above) the method declaration: `[DllImport(@"my.dll", ...] public static extern int get_card(byte n,ref uint state);`. You can call `get_card()` as usual: `uint state = 123; byte n = 15; int result = MyClass.get_card(n, ref state);`

Comment: This **absolutely is not** a "stupid beginners question" - P/Invoke and `extern` method imports is something that most C# developers never need to get involved with, which is fortunate because it is messy and hard to get right! As a side note: without knowing the intent of `state`, it is hard to know whether it is best represented as a `ref uint` vs an unmanaged pointer (`uint*`) - the latter being more common if it is more like an array-start pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `DllImportAttribute` must be put *before* the method it describes:

```
public static class MyClass {
   ...
   // Since you don't use String, StringBuilder etc. 
   // CharSet = CharSet.Ansi is redundant and can be omitted
  [DllImport(@"my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern int get_card(byte n, ref uint state);
   ...
}
```

Having `get_card` method declared, you can use it as usual, as any other method (and .Net will *marshall* the arguments):

```
...
byte n = 123;
uint state = 456;

int result = MyClass.get_card(n, ref state);  
...
```